# is it possible to write a SQL query that does this without a subselect?

Tags: sql, one-to-many, subquery

Imagine a relation one to many, for example:

```
Mail: subject, date etc 
Recipient: address
```

Is it possible to do this query **WITHOUT using a subselect**: all mail received by abc@domain.com that did not have another recipient from the same domain @domain.com??

the only way I can find is using a subselect:

```
select mail m, recipient r where m.pkm=r.pkm 
and (r.address='abc@domain.com')
and not exists (select * from mail ms, recipient rs where m.pkm=ms.pkm and ms.pkm=rs.pkm and rs.address<>'abc@domain.com' and rs.address like '%@domain.com')
```

Comment: You might want to extract the domain in it's own field and index it, as `like '%xxx'` queries takes a lot of time.

Comment: Nekresh, thanks for the suggestion but the schema already exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select m.*, r1.* 
from mail m
inner join recipient r1 on m.pkm=r1.pkm
left join recipient r2 on m.pkm=r2.pkm and r2.address<>'abc@domain.com' and r2.address like '%@domain.com'
where r2.pkm is null
and r1.address='abc@domain.com'
```

Comment: mmm, I am testing this but it gives me wrong results....I don't understand it very well, but for starters there should be a (r.address='abc@domain.com') condition somewhere, right??

Comment: works fine now, thanks. I'll test in a db with enough data, but should this query be faster than the subselect one?

Comment: I can't say if this query is fatser in general, it widely depends on your RDMBS, but it's not slower in any case

Comment: lweller, FYI, tested in a db real data and a million rows in mail, your query is about 4 times faster. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is any better than your original! -- it still has a sub-select -- but allows for domains to be other than the literal 'domain.com'.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM mail m
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT pkm
    FROM recipient
    GROUP BY pkm, SUBSTRING(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) + 1, 1000)
    HAVING COUNT(SUBSTRING(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) + 1, 1000))  = 1
) r
ON m.pkm = r.pkm
```

hth, R